# C++ Runtime error on Mac 10.7/10.8

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, dylib

I am using Eclipse, GCC 4.8 and building C++ project on both Mac OS 10.7 and 10.8. For the most of the time, the project builds and runs properly except for some specific functions. For example:

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    string a = "test";
    string b = "-bla";
    string c;
    c = a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

The compile is successful:

> Build of configuration Debug for project Working **
>
> make all  Building file: ../working.cpp Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler g++
>   -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"working.d" -MT"working.d" -o "working.o" "../working.cpp" Finished building: ../working.cpp   Building target: Working Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
>   g++  -o "Working"  ./working.o    Finished building target: Working
>
> Build Finished **

However, I received this runtime error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZNSsaSEOSs
  Referenced from: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/zeroliu/Study/CPP/Working/Debug/Working
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZNSsaSEOSs
  Referenced from: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/zeroliu/Study/CPP/Working/Debug/Working
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
```

I find that the error comes from

```
string c;
c = a + b;
```

The interesting thing is, if I make the following changes:

```
string c = a+b;
```

or

```
c = a;
```

The programs runs perfectly.

Anyone has any ideas about what happens here? Thanks

Comment: GCC 4.8 has not yet been released. You are using some form of the latest GCC trunk, which is still in stage 1 (i.e. development stage, hence not very stable). I suggest to use GCC 4.7 (i.e. GCC 4.7.2 release)

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right. The bug probably comes from the beta version of GCC 4.8 and solved the problem by reverting GCC back to 4.7.2.

Comment: Then, please report that bug on http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/